# Banco de Dados com muitas alterações

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql

## Situação

Estou fazendo um sistema para uma Drogaria. O Cliente pode entrar na farmacia e pegar produtos só da gôndula e passar diretamente no caixa, ou pode passar no balcão e pegar só o antibiótico no balcão com farmacêutico, ou também pode passar pelo balcão e pela gôndula e depois passar no caixa.

Quando o cliente passa pelo balcão para pegar um antibiótico com bula, ele recebe uma **comanda com um número**, e o número da comanda está atrelada ao antibiótico que ele pegou com o farmacêutico.

Se o cliente pegar um produto na gôndula, o produto não será colocado na comanda, ele poderá passar o produto direto no caixa.

Quando o cliente passa no caixa, quem está no caixa coloca o número da comanda (se tiver) que exibirá os produtos pegados no balcão mais os produtos pegados na gôndula (se tiver). Finalizado a compra, o sistema apaga os dados da comanda.

## Meu Problema

**A comanda varia constantemente os dados armazenados.** Compensa armazenar no MySQL os dados da comanda?Ou existe uma forma de passar essa alteração de uma forma mais eficiente reduzindo as alterações no MySQL? Qual seria o melhor método?

Estive pensando que seria muito bom se tivesse um array para armazenar esses produtos na comanda, e se tivesse uma forma de passar este array entre o computador do balcão e o computador do caixa.

Estou aberto a sugestões, qual linguagem seria a mais adequada? O que devo utilizar? Qual é o método?

#### Informações Adicionais

- Está sendo desenvolvido utilizando HTML, JS, PHP e MySQL.
- Será hospedado em um Servidor Ubuntu Server

Comment: tem que armazenar no banco sim, isso também é conhecido como pré-venda, e se seu estado estiver com legislação vigente do PAF-ECF, você tem que manter os itens na pré-venda em aberto por 2 dias (salvo engano), e depois emitir os itens no ECF e cancelar a venda. Se não estiver com PAF-ECF, máis fácil, porém, sempre será necessário armazenar no banco

Comment: Nesta situação, a página web é utilizada como sistema interno da loja. A comanda é uma espécie de pré venda, mas dura só no máximo um dia, já que a pessoa não leva a comanda para casa.

Comment: O que é feito com a comanda ? Comissão , controle ou algo assim ? Pode ser um problema de processo.Creio que fala de uma compra física , não ?

Comment: @Motta A comanda possuí um número. Os produtos com receita são colocados em uma bolsa a parte e os produtos dentro dessa bolsa são cadastrados relativos ao número da comanda.

Comment: A minha pergunta é :precisa guardar o número da comanda !?

Comment: Sim, o numero da comanda é um ID. A comanda possuí produtos cadastrados relacionados ao ID da comanda. Funciona como uma farmácia normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o problema for só esse, dá pra você criar um sistema de comunicação entre os computadores com `AJAX` e salvar via cookie no navegador. Mas recomendo vc utilizar o banco pra armazenar por questões de facilidade e também por causa da persistência que é maior, pra vc enviar e receber os dados `AJAX` precisaria de todos os computadores em rede, se algum computador "caisse" então dados seriam perdidos, o que não aconteceria com o banco de dados. Caso também o cliente queira depois um sistema pra outra plataforma, seria bem mais fácil de implementar depois com  o servidor já funcionando tudo certinho...